# pyplot is creating many different lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph some functions which for some reason look like they are composed of smaller fuzzy lines instead of being single lines.

[image: This is the image]

The four functions on these two graphs are simply lists of numbers that I created in a for loop.

```
for i in range(iters):

    #zero the gradients
    amsgrad.zero_grad()
    adam.zero_grad()

    #Perform an optimization step
    adam.step(closure_adam)
    amsgrad.step(closure_amsgrad)

    #Clamp the variables between -1 and 1
    x_var_adam.data = x_var_adam.data.clamp(-1,1)
    x_var_amsgrad.data = x_var_amsgrad.data.clamp(-1,1)

    #Calculate the regret
    adam_regret = regret(total_loss_adam,total_min_loss_adam,t)
    ams_regret = regret(total_loss_amsgrad,total_min_loss_amsgrad,t)

    #Store regret
    regret_adam_hist.append(adam_regret)
    regret_amsgrad_hist.append(ams_regret)

    #Store the x_t values
    x_var_adam_hist.append(x_var_adam.data[0])
    x_var_amsgrad_hist.append(x_var_amsgrad.data[0])

    #Adjust learning rate by dividing by sqrt(t)
    adjust_learning_rate(adam,my_lr,t)
    adjust_learning_rate(amsgrad,my_lr,t)
    t+=1

# this is the second photo
x = np.arange(0,iters)
plt.clf()
plt.xlabel("Iterations")
plt.ylabel("$R_t/t$")
plt.plot(x,regret_adam_hist, label="adam", c='b', ls='--')
plt.plot(x,regret_amsgrad_hist,label="amsgrad",c='g')
plt.axis([0, iters, 0, 0.5])
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,10)
plt.show()

plt.clf()

# this is the first photo
x = np.arange(0,iters+1)
plt.plot(x, x_var_adam_hist, label="adam", c='b', ls='--')
plt.xlabel("Iterations")
plt.ylabel("$x_t$")
plt.plot(x, x_var_amsgrad_hist, label="amsgrad", c='g', ls='dotted')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,10)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

I'm not sure why pyplot is giving me these graphs that look like it's calculating multiple lines. This is the regret function that is being plotted above:

[image: Regret]

These should all look like smooth lines. I've checked the following:

```
for n in regret_amsgrad_hist:
assert (type(n) == float)
assert (type(regret_amsgrad_hist) == list)
assert (len(regret_amsgrad_hist) == 60000)
```

I don't see what could be causing it to be "thick" as to look like a less than or equal to function or something. Does anyone have any ideas as to why my graph is not a simply 2 smooth functions in both graphs?

The only thing unusual I guess about these functions is that every 101 iterations, the function spikes in the opposite direction. Here are some sample values of the second picture ( second graph ) (average regret [image]) :

https://pastebin.com/UrYGkFHT

EDIT: I've realized there's nothing wrong with my function, but it seems that it's squishing together the oscillations into a single thick line. Is there any way to avoid this? For example :

This:
[image: iters=60000]

looks like this with less examples:

[image: iters=3000]

Comment: if you zoom in do you see smooth lines?

Comment: If you zoom in on the first photo, you can see that the green function If I replot the graph to only show a smaller portion, you still see multiple squiggly lines in place of a single line: https://i.imgur.com/6VY2zSk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was oscillating so much had to do with the fact that the function is actually oscillating a lot. In the graph I was trying to reproduce, the graph did not appear to be oscillating. This was because they used **plt.semilogx** on the x axis which scaled out the oscillations to appear as a solid line.

The solution was to use plt.semilogx on the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

As your sample to plot is highly oscillating, this is the expected behavior of pyplot when you use a solid line.

If you want to represent your oscillating  sample without  this large solid line due to the oscillations, the best option is to only use symbols and no line.